# Help with Select, Join across multiple tables with CodeIgniter - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, join

I am trying to make a query in Codeigniter that will allow a user to retrieve a record they submitted in the past to my database.

This is my schema:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSHSQ.png

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do for some of my tables

**For example 1:M or M:M**

1. 1 *procedure* has 1 or many *procedure_event*
2. a *procedure_event* may or may not have use resources
3. 1 procedure has 1 or many staff

I think I need to use Select, Joins for this and I have got some of it completed but for the Many to Many relationships and linked tables I am confused how to do them.

This is what I have got so far in terms of code but it is not returning any rows so I think it is wrong:

```
    public function view_record($record_id)
    {
        //The criteria used for WHERE is a variable with array of procedure_id = record_id that is passed to function
        $criteria = array 
        (
            'procedure_id' => $record_id
        );

        //this selects the columns from procedure table for use in joins 
        $this->db->select('procedure.procedure_id, procedure.patient_id, procedure.department_id, procedure.name_id , procedure.dosage_id');
        //this is the table I want to use the columns from
        $this->db->from ('procedure');

        //this joins the patient row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
        $this->db->join('patient', 'patient.patient_id = procedure.patient_id', 'inner');

        //this joins the department row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
        $this->db->join('department', 'department.department_id = procedure.department_id', 'inner');

        //this joins the procedure_name row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
        $this->db->join('procedure_name', 'procedure_name.procedure_name_id = procedure.name_id', 'inner');

        //this joins the dosage row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
        $this->db->join('dosage', 'dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id', 'inner');

        //this selects the row in procedure table that matches the record number
        $this->db->where('procedure_id', $record_id);

        /*
        Code for other tables:
        I need help with

        procedure_event, staff, resources, hr

        */

        //this part I think is wrong
        $result = $this->db->get();


        //
        if ($result->num_rows >0)
        {
            echo "There is Data!";

        }

        else
        {
            echo "No Data!";

        }
```

}

I get back a message saying **"No Records"** however there is data in my tables etc:

So my query so far must be wrong.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'd use left join if yuo're planing to have relation with zero elements on one hand

Comment: yes, left join means that you want to have the left hand table data even if it does not join with the right hand table, having said that the row will have this structure: left_table.a,left_table.b,NULL,NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I personally consider it easier to write as complex queries as this on in pure text, rather then using Active Records.

All your joins uses inner; that is that all rows need to find a partner in the other table. If any of these doesn't exist you get 0 rows. Consider using LEFT JOIN, as previously suggested.

Do all of these tables contain data at the moment?

Do need absolutely a partner row in everyone of these tables, or do you count on cases where rows are missing?

Comment: Hi thanks Robin, some records wont contain data in some tables e.g. sometime a procedure does not have a dosage so the dosage table has no data, each procedure must have a minimum of one staff row and one event row

Comment: Try for instance to change:
$this->db->join('department', 'department.department_id = procedure.department_id', 'inner');
To:
        $this->db->join('department', 'department.department_id = procedure.department_id', 'left');

That is change 'inner' to 'left' on the tables which you know there might be no connection at.

Comment: Thanks alot Robin! It works now it is returning a matching record to the id I want :)

Now how should I take my linked tables and the Many to Many relationship tables e.g. procedure_event -> resources? 

Thanks again